# Memory leak after algorithm in Rails?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I wrote an algorithm inspired by the merge part of the merge sort.

```
  def self.merge(arr)
    if arr.length == 1
      return arr
    end
    groups = []
    (0...-(-arr.length/2)).each do |i|
      groups << []
      if !arr[2*i+1].nil?
        arr[2*i].each do |cal1|
          arr[2*i+1].each do |cal2|
            mergecal = func(cal1,cal2)
            if mergecal
              groups[i] << mergecal
            else
              mergecal = nil
            end
          end
        end
      else
        groups[i] = arr[2*i]
      end
    end
    arr = nil
    return merge(groups)
  end
```

After the page using this algorithm is rendered, Task Manager reported around 500MB of RAM usage. Then by refreshing the same page again, memory usage have now reached 1GB. I tried adding `GC.start(full_mark: true)` to the controller just after the function call, but nothing seems to have changed. I'm not sure whether the memory leak has to code with my code or Ruby itself.

Comment: Do you have any input example?

Comment: Checkout this gem:  
https://github.com/schneems/derailed_benchmarks

Comment: What is the point of doubly negating? `-(-arr.length/2)`

Comment: @EricDuminil It feeds an array `[[obj1], [obj2], [obj3]]` where the objects are custom objects

Comment: @sawa It's just a lazy way to take the ceil without the function.

Comment: I see. It looks like a clever way.

Comment: I don't see the definition of func in the code you supplied, so there might be something important missing from this description. Also useful to mention what version of Ruby/Rails you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby garbage collection doesn't immediately reduce the amount of memory your ruby program has allocated. Memory allocation is expensive so even if the objects you create are immediately collected by GC the memory is slowly released back to the OS. If you think this function has a memory leak you should try running it in a non-rails process where you have more control over object lifecycles. You can use [GC.stat](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/GC.html#method-c-stat) to get information about the number of live and free objects before and after you run the GC. It's also worth reading up on how ruby GC works I like [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/ruby-uses-memory/).

Comment: Oh that was a bummer. I think you're right. I have to call the `GC.start` over and over as the algorithm allocates way too much memory for the GC to free it in one shot.